# If $\mathbf{X}_1$ and $\mathbf{X}_2$ are symmetries, then so is $[\mathbf{X}_1,\mathbf{X}_2]$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lie-algebras, symmetry

**Background:** Suppose we have a differential equation 
$$
y^{(n)}=\omega(x,y,y',\ldots,y^{(n-1)})
$$
that satisfies two symmetries $\mathbf{X}_1$ and $\mathbf{X}_2$. That is, if
$$
\mathbf{A}:=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+y'\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+\cdots+\omega\frac{\partial}{\partial y^{(n-1)}},
$$
then we have
$$
[\mathbf{X}_1,\mathbf{A}]=\lambda_1\mathbf{A},\quad[\mathbf{X}_2,\mathbf{A}]=\lambda_2\mathbf{A}
$$
for some functions $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$ of $x,y,\ldots,y^{(n-1)}$. $[\cdot,\cdot]$ is the commutator and is defined by $[A,B]=AB-BA$.

**Question:** How can we show that $[\mathbf{X}_1,\mathbf{X}_2]$ is again a symmetry?

**Atempt:** We must show that $[[\mathbf{X}_1,\mathbf{X}_2],\mathbf{A}]=\rho\mathbf{A}$ for some function $\rho$. By the [Jacobi identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_identity), we have
$$
[[\mathbf{X}_1,\mathbf{X}_2],\mathbf{A}]=[\mathbf{X}_1,\lambda_2\mathbf{A}]-[\mathbf{X}_2,\lambda_1\mathbf{A}]
$$
In my [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521366895), they continue from here and just write
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
[[\mathbf{X}_1,\mathbf{X}_2],\mathbf{A}] &=& [\mathbf{X}_1,\lambda_2\mathbf{A}]-[\mathbf{X}_2,\lambda_1\mathbf{A}] \\
&=&\lambda_2\lambda_1\mathbf{A}+(\mathbf{X}_1\lambda_2)\mathbf{A}-\lambda_2\lambda_1\mathbf{A}-(\mathbf{X}_2\lambda_1)\mathbf{A} \\
&=&\rho\mathbf{A}
\end{eqnarray}
$$
**My Problem: I don't see how can we go from the first line to the second.**

If we use the definition of commutators, we have

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
[[\mathbf{X}_1,\mathbf{X}_2],\mathbf{A}] &=& [\mathbf{X}_1,\lambda_2\mathbf{A}]-[\mathbf{X}_2,\lambda_1\mathbf{A}] \\
&=&\mathbf{X}_1\lambda_2\mathbf{A}-\lambda_2\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}_1-\mathbf{X}_2\lambda_1\mathbf{A}+\lambda_1\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}_2
\end{eqnarray}
$$
and they say that this is equal to 
$$\lambda_2\lambda_1\mathbf{A} + (\mathbf{X}_1\lambda_2)\mathbf{A}-\lambda_2\lambda_1\mathbf{A}-(\mathbf{X}_2\lambda_1)\mathbf{A} = (\mathbf{X}_1\lambda_2)\mathbf{A}-(\mathbf{X}_2\lambda_1)\mathbf{A},$$
so in other words, they claim that
$$\lambda_1\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}_2=\lambda_2\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}_1$$
or equivalently
$$
\lambda_1 \mathbf{X}_2 \mathbf{A}=\lambda_2\mathbf{X}_1\mathbf{A}
$$
**Why?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remember the Jacobi identity then you just have to remember how the commutator behaves when you have a product by a function:
$$
[X,fY]=(Xf)Y+f[X,Y]
$$
and then the result follows

Comment: They don't talk about this identity in my book. Where does that come from? From the definition, I get $$[X,fY]=X(fY)-(fY)X=XfY+f(XY-YX)-fXY=(Xf)Y+f[X,Y]-fXY$$. So $fXY=0$? This is the part I don't understand.

Comment: I don't understand quite well your notation, what is the difference between $XfY$ and $(Xf)Y$? I believe that $XfY=(Xf)Y+fXY$ and that is why you cancel out the term $fXY$ there is one positive and one negative.